# IsLoggedIn http service with API in Angular

Tags: angular, api, authentication, passport.js

```
router.get('/isloggedin', (req, res) => {
    if(req.user){
        return res.json({'isLogged': true});
    }
    return res.json({'isLogged': false});
})
```

As you can see from above, my node backend sends a JSON response depending on if the user exists. On my frontend, I want to toggle a variable in a user service which I can use in templates depending on if its true or false, however I've been having a lot of trouble with it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response  } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor (private http: Http) {}
    isLoggedIn(){
        this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/auth/isloggedin")
        .map(res => res.json()).toPromise();
    }

}
```

This is all I have right now. How would I go about setting something like this up? I want to be able to use a variable from my auth service in templates but I run into issues such as infinite looping when I subscribe to the function.

HTML code:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn() | async">
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You ever try to console.log the data coming back from the call?

Comment: Once I subscribe to the observable or convert it to a promise, yes, but I only want there to be 1 http response at the start of a page load. All I want is to get the user status, store it in a variable and use it in my code.

Comment: Can I see your subscription piece of code?

Comment: I edited the main post to show both HTML code and updated authService. Whenever I run the app it just sends hundreds of calls to the server every second and does it infinitely. I only want 1 http call.

Comment: I'm not sure about your approach. But can't you call the authService.isLoggedIn in the ts then assign the result back to a variable then ngIf based on that variable? Or was that what you tried?

Comment: You could put your http call into the constructor. As far as I know injectables act as Singletons if used properly, therefore the call will only be made once and the variable will be set and accessible afterwards

Comment: You legend @BenediktSchmidt post it as an answer so I can rate u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, to sum it up with some code, here's a possible solution.

You're currently binding the return value of `isLoggedIn()` to your html template. Unfortunately your function does not return anything which is probably why angular tries to call it over and over again (you're calling the backend, but there's no `return` in your function). But even if it would return the observable that you're calling, it would still be suboptimal, because it's actually a rather complicated call that takes quite some time and it does not necessarily need to be called multiple times after all. Just imagine you had multiple `*ngIf` sections in your code that all rely on the login state. This would mean that angular would call the backend for every `*ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn() | async"` in your template. That's a lot of overhead.

For our case here it would be much better to get the login information **once** on initialization and safe the state in a variable. You can use the constructor of your service for this. With angulars dependency injection system, services are considered singletons (if used correctly). I quote from [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection):

> Services are singletons within the scope of an injector. There is at
>   most one instance of a service in a given injector.
>
> There is only one root injector and the UserService is registered with
>   that injector. Therefore, there can be just one UserService instance
>   in the entire app and every class that injects UserService get this
>   service instance.

That means the constructor of your service is called only once. So you can be sure if you make your backend call inside the constructor, it will be the first thing the service does and it will be only time it does it. That's good for us, way less backend calls here. The result is going to be saved in a variable for public usage.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor (private http: Http) {
        // one time call to get the login status
       this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/auth/isloggedin").subscribe(data=>{
            // save the state in the variable
            this.isLogged = (<any>data).isLogged;
        });
    }

    // this is our variable
    isLogged:boolean =false;
}
```

Now real quick into the html template. We're not using `isLoggedIn()` as a binding anymore. We can just use the variable that we're setting after the service was created.

```
<li *ngIf="authService.isLogged">
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
</li>
```

That's looking good. Now if you have other html tags where you need to check for the login state, you can use the exact same variable without making multiple calls gain.

## recap

Some things needed to be changed to make sure that the code not only works, but also is taking less time and other resources (like bandwith). For that we made sure that:

- the `isLoggedIn` request is only performed once --> not bound in the template anymore
- the `isLoggedIn` request is called initially --> placed in the constructor
- the state can be referenced multiple times wihout requesting the backend again --> safed in a variable that is referenced in the template

## side note

With this variable in your Service, logging in and out is quite easy too. When you login through your frontend, you can set the variable to true when the login was successfull. When you logout you can just set it to false.

```
login(username, password) {
    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/auth/login", {username: username, password: password}).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(() => {
        this.isLogged=true;
    });
}
logout() {
    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/auth/logout", {}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(() => {
        this.isLogged = false;
    });
}
```